# STDDEV function and with clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle. I have table like:

```
Company   Employee   salary
   A1       Jim     122000
...
```

I want to return the company with the highest number of employee whose salary is above 2 standard deviations (~>95%). Here is my code

```
With Com_2Std as (
Select company-name, AVG(salary)+2*STDDEV(salary) as AboveS
From works
Group By company-name)

Select company-name, count(employee-name) as ENumber
From works
Where ENumber=MAX(
Select  count(a.employee-name)
From works a, Com_2Std b
Where  a.company-name=b.company-name
And a.salary>b.AboveS;
Group by a.company-name)
Group by company-name;
```

I have two quesions:

(1) I can't access to oracle today and can't test it. Is my code correct please?

(2) It looks quite complicated, any way to simplify it please?

Comment: No, you can't use the MAX() that way. I hesitate to try writing an Oracle version for you since I'm less familiar with some of its particularities in syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with Com_2Std as (
    select company-name, AVG(salary)+2*STDDEV(salary) as AboveS
    from works
    group by company-name
),
CompanyCount as (
    select a.company-name, count(*) as CountAboveS
    from
        works a
        inner join Com_2Std b on a.company-name=b.company-name
    where
        a.salary > b.AboveS
    group by a.company-name
)
select company-name
from CompanyCount
where CountAboveS = (select max(CountAboveS) from CompanyCount)
```

This ought to be close. It will produce ties as well.